# How can I dynamically load shared libraries in a Jenkinsfile and execute their same-named global variable methods?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries, jenkins-shared-libraries

I want to load variably-named shared libraries in my Jenkinsfiles sequentially, and run a global variable method of the same name in each one.
I.e. as pseudocode, what I want to do is:

```
for lib in in [foo, bar]:
  load shared library(lib)
  run the shared library's global variable method named 'func()'
```

I tried implementing this as follows:

```
// Jenkinsfile
pipeline {
  agent any

    stages {
      stage('1') {
        steps {
          testLoadLib()
        }
      }
    }
}

void testLoadLib() {
  runGlobalVariableMethod('foo@dev')
  runGlobalVariableMethod('bar@dev')
}

void runGlobalVariableMethod(String libraryName) {
  def lib = library(libraryName)
  def d = [:]
  func.func(d)
}
```

```
// shared_lib_foo
// vars/func.groovy

def func(d) {
  println("foo func.groovy:func()")
}
```

```
// shared_lib_bar
// vars/func.groovy

def func(d) {
  println("bar func.groovy:func()")
}
```

The shared libraries have been configured as Jenkins Global Pipeline Libraries as follows:
[image]

[image]

On running the Jenkins pipeline, `func.func()` from the `foo@dev` shared library is run twice, instead of from `foo@dev` once, then `bar@dev` next.
I.e.:
actual output (edited for brevity):

```
foo func.groovy:func()
foo func.groovy:func()
```

desired output:

```
foo func.groovy:func()
bar func.groovy:func()
```

**Question: between the Jenkinsfile and the Jenkins shared libraries, how can I implement the desired behavior?**
The desired behavior being: I want to load multiple shared libraries, iteratively, and run each one's global variable method (that has the same name).
One might describe this as a plugin architecture: load a variable/specifiable shared library, and run an expected function within it.

---

The unedited Jenkins pipeline output (for better context) shows that it appears to be checking out the correct shared libraries -- I see correct references to the respective shared libraries' git repository and commit-ids:

```
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (1)
[Pipeline] library
Loading library foo@dev
Attempting to resolve dev from remote references...
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.20.1'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -- ssh://git@bitbucket.company.com:8999/prj/foo.git # timeout=10
Found match: refs/heads/dev revision 12419a423b1da2827215bca89aaa0f1fdba7e6ae
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential f3d14e3a-851b-4837-bbfd-31292f16e310
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /home/user/workspace/wip@libs/006019fd942f0d37b69f2cd051be759efa34f738b3937627946801f48dd03a7c/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > /usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url ssh://git@bitbucket.company.com:8999/prj/foo.git # timeout=10
Fetching without tags
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@bitbucket.company.com:8999/prj/foo.git
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.20.1'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > /usr/bin/git fetch --no-tags --force --progress -- ssh://git@bitbucket.company.com:8999/prj/foo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 12419a423b1da2827215bca89aaa0f1fdba7e6ae (dev)
 > /usr/bin/git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git checkout -f 12419a423b1da2827215bca89aaa0f1fdba7e6ae # timeout=10
Commit message: "wip"
 > /usr/bin/git rev-list --no-walk 12419a423b1da2827215bca89aaa0f1fdba7e6ae # timeout=10
[Pipeline] echo
foo func.groovy:func()
[Pipeline] library
Loading library bar@dev
Attempting to resolve dev from remote references...
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.20.1'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -- ssh://git@bitbucket.company.com:8999/prj/bar.git # timeout=10
Found match: refs/heads/dev revision 52bc665d148fd2109831f484e604f1e3f82e895b
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential f3d14e3a-851b-4837-bbfd-31292f16e310
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /home/user/workspace/wip@libs/87e71759ef01c569f052b9dc73ff630019f50862832bd0583331e87472373144/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > /usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url ssh://git@bitbucket.company.com:8999/prj/bar.git # timeout=10
Fetching without tags
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@bitbucket.company.com:8999/prj/bar.git
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.20.1'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > /usr/bin/git fetch --no-tags --force --progress -- ssh://git@bitbucket.company.com:8999/prj/bar.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 52bc665d148fd2109831f484e604f1e3f82e895b (dev)
 > /usr/bin/git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git checkout -f 52bc665d148fd2109831f484e604f1e3f82e895b # timeout=10
Commit message: "wip"
 > /usr/bin/git rev-list --no-walk 52bc665d148fd2109831f484e604f1e3f82e895b # timeout=10
[Pipeline] echo
foo func.groovy:func()
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr:** it appears that:

- The return-value of `library` ([loads a shared library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#accessing-steps)) isn't an object on which you can invoke the shared library's global variable methods.
- The return-value of `load` ([load a "local" Groovy script](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#-load-evaluate-a-groovy-source-file-into-the-pipeline-script)) is an object on which you can invoke the Groovy script's global variable methods.

Use `load` to load Groovy scripts from the local filesystem instead of `library` to load from source control.

---

**The ugly details:** the closest I've been able to achieve to an answer to the question asked is to use the [`load`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#-load-evaluate-a-groovy-source-file-into-the-pipeline-script) function, instead of `library`.

`library` loads groovy scripts directly from SCM, which may or may not be in the same repo as the Jenkinsfile itself.

`load` seems specifically only able to load from the local filesystem, wherever the `Jenkinsfile` exists.

Critical to this question, though, `library` seems unwilling to override global variable functions if newly-loaded shared libraries have groovy scripts with the same filename and function names. Also, `library` seems to not return any kind of object to which its functions are scoped.

This shortcoming appears to be absent with the `load` function: it returns an object to which the loaded groovy script's functions are scoped. This behavior is in line with lazy-loading shared libraries, e.g. with C's `dlopen` and `dlsym` functions.

This is perhaps better illustrated by example:

```
// Jenkinsfile
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('1') {
      steps {
        testLibrary()
      }
    }
  }
}

def testLibrary() {
  def repo_prefix = "ssh://git@bitbucket.company.com:8999/prj/"
  def repo_suffix = ".git"
  def branch = "@dev"
  def cred_id = 'ssh_credz'
  def lib_names = ['foo', 'bar']

  for (String lib_name in lib_names) {
    def lib = library(identifier: lib_name + branch, retriever: modernSCM(
        [$class: 'GitSCMSource',
         remote: repo_prefix + lib_name + repo_suffix,
         credentialsId: credz,
         ]))
    // lib.func(42) // java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: null
    func.func(42) // Not useful because global variable `func` is set
                  // in the first iteration of the for-loop but not
                  // overridden by subsequent iterations.
  }
}
```

The relevant output of running this Jenkins pipeline, as noted in the original post, is:

```
Loading library foo@dev
...
Found match: refs/heads/dev revision 288d0f105fa21be1ea8c0245c4dddcf16a5340c9
...
foo func.groovy:func()
...
Loading library bar@dev
...
Found match: refs/heads/dev revision 989b86211ff225b0d576b854d959b5da6ef641af
...
foo func.groovy:func()
```

This may be compared with equivalent-intent use of the `load` function:

```
// Jenkinsfile
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('1') {
      steps {
        testLoad()
      }
    }
  }
}

def testLoad() {
  def lib_names = ['foo', 'bar']

  for (String lib_name in lib_names) {
    stage(lib_name) {
      def lib_file = lib_name + '.groovy'
      def lib = load lib_file

      lib.func(42);
    }
  }
}
```

Running this Jenkins pipeline reveals the desired output:

```
foo func.groovy:func()
bar func.groovy:func()
```

In terms of implementation, the relevant differences are:

1. To use `load`, the groovy script filenames need to be different, since you're `load`ing by filename.
2. The groovy scripts to be loaded must be in the same filesystem as the Jenkinsfile. I've found it convenient to simply include the `.groovy` files in the same folder and git repo as the `Jenkinsfile`.

An arguable demerit of this approach is that the loaded groovy script isn't as "decoupled" from the Jenkins pipeline as a true shared library: e.g. the groovy scripts don't exist in a separate git repo, which could be modified and maintained independent from the Jenkinsfile's git repo.
But I think with the right structure and workflow, the detriments can be minimized.
And this nicely achieves the desired goal: I can successively load multiple groovy scripts and execute each one's same-named global variable function.