# What is the rationale behind Jenkins's `load` vs. `library` functions?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-shared-libraries

This question follows from [How can I dynamically load shared libraries in a Jenkinsfile and execute their same-named global variable methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76050388/how-can-i-dynamically-load-shared-libraries-in-a-jenkinsfile-and-execute-their-s/76150404#76150404)

**Why does `load` return an object that scopes the loaded Groovy script's global variable methods whereas `library` does not?**

I would like to understand the design/intent of [`load`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#-load-evaluate-a-groovy-source-file-into-the-pipeline-script) vs. [`library`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#accessing-steps).
The linked documentation hasn't helped: it explains *how* to use the functions, but doesn't go into the rationale for why the functions behave as they do.
It seems like the only relevant difference between the two functions is where the Groovy scripts are loaded from: the local filesystem vs. a separate source control repo.
It seems like a crippling deficiency of `library` to load everything into the global scope while not allow overriding previously-loaded content with subsequent calls to `library`.

As an example of what I'm asking: in the code below, I want to implement a "plugin"-style mechanism by which the Jenkinsfile loads Groovy scripts, each of which implements a function with the same name/signature.
This is achievable with `load` because the functions loaded by `load` are scoped to the return-value of `load`.
This does not seem to be achievable with `library`: I don't know what `library` returns, but unlike `load`, it's not an object on which I can invoke the shared library's global variable methods. Moreover, the first invocation of `library` loads the shared library's global variable methods into the filename's scope, and subsequent invocations do not override what was loaded by the first invocation.

---

Shared-library `foo` is laid out like this:

```
.
└── vars
    └── func.groovy
```

```
// foo shared-lib
// vars/func.groovy

def func(d) {
  println("shared-lib foo")
}

return this
```

---

Shared-library `bar` is laid out like this (it is the same layout as `foo`):

```
.
└── vars
    └── func.groovy
```

```
// bar shared-lib
// vars/func.groovy

def func(d) {
  println("shared-lib bar")
}

return this
```

---

The Jenkinsfile repo is laid out like this:

```
.
├── bar.groovy
├── foo.groovy
└── jenkinsfile
```

```
// foo.groovy

def func(d) {
  println("foo.groovy")
}

return this
```

```
// bar.groovy

def func(d) {
  println("bar.groovy")
}

return this
```

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('1') {
      steps {
        testLoad()
        testLibrary()
      }
    }
  }
}

def testLoad() {
  def lib_names = ['foo', 'bar']

  for (String lib_name in lib_names) {
    stage(lib_name) {
      def lib_file = lib_name + '.groovy'

      // The functions loaded by `load` are scoped to
      // the object `lib` -- super useful!
      def lib = load lib_file

      lib.func(42);
    }
  }
}

def testLibrary() {
  def repo_prefix = "ssh://git@bitbucket.company.com:8999/prj/"
  def repo_suffix = ".git"
  def branch = "@dev"
  def cred_id = 'ssh_credz'
  def lib_names = ['foo', 'bar']

  for (String lib_name in lib_names) {
    // The functions loaded by `library` are not scoped to
    // the object `lib` >:(
    def lib = library(identifier: lib_name + branch, retriever: modernSCM(
        [$class: 'GitSCMSource',
         remote: repo_prefix + lib_name + repo_suffix,
         credentialsId: cred_id,
         ]))

    // lib.func(42) // java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: null

    func.func(42) // Not useful because global variable `func` is set
                  // by the first call to `library` and not overridden
                  // by subsequent calls.
  }
}
```

The relevant output of this pipeline is:

```
foo.groovy
...
bar.groovy
...
Loading library foo@dev
...
shared-lib foo
...
Loading library bar@dev
...
shared-lib foo
```

---

**Update:** a comment from @daggett brought up the `call()` method. I tried implementing a `call()` function in the shared libraries, and the behavior is unchanged.
If shared-libraries `foo` and `bar` both have `func.groovy` and both implement `def call(){...}`, then yes, I can invoke `func()` as a shortcut for that shared library's primary function (instead of invoking `func.func()`), but still the problem described in the original post remains: if I do `library foo@dev...` then `library bar@dev...` then call `func()`, then `foo`'s `call()` is invoked, rather than `bar`'s.
I.e. I'd like to be able to load shared libraries (Groovy scripts) successively, and for the most recently-loaded one to "take effect" if it implements the same function as a previously-loaded one.
This is achievable with `load`, but so far appears to not be achievable with `library`.
If "it is what it is", I can accept that, but what I'm trying to learn, with this question, is the rationale behind this difference between `load` and `library`, because this seems a crippling limitation of `library` vs. `load`.

Comment: to my experience in `vars/` better to define just one function per file: `def call(x){...}` - then you could call it by file name: `vars/func.groovy` => `func(x)` which is a shortage for `func.call(x)`. return at the end of lib file is not required.

Comment: @daggett That depends on area(s) of responsibility of the global var methods, and I would suggest good organization would be preferred over the capability to omit the prefix in the namespace.

Comment: @daggett - you're correct...but again, the issue I'm questioning is: if you have two shared-libraries who both define `vars/func.groovy` with function `call()`, and if you load those shared library with `library()`, then only the first one "takes effect". There's no way I could find to load the second shared library and run its `call()` global variable method.